# how to add page switching animation effect in different content of 1 UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, swipe

I have an UIViewController on showing my friends' data. This controller supports swipe gesture: swipe the screen left will transfer to next friend's data, to right back to previous. so it is only 1 UIViewController, the whole process just reloads new data and refreshes UI when different content reading from server api returns.

is it possible that adding a page switch effect in swipe and content change, like they are in different UIViewController? my code is basically like this structure,

1.[passing friend id, get server api return];
2.[parsing it and populate content on UI];
3.[swipe detect];
4.[reload data by passing a new friend id then repeat 1-4];

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use this structure: 1 parent controller, 2 children controllers. Whenever a turn-the-page action is triggered, the parent dismisses the current child and presents the other.

In this way you can implement the turn-the-page animation with ease, with the **UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp** system animation effect.

Comment: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp is only represented in iOS4 and later, just for information if he have to support older versions

Comment: thanks everyone. now I have achieve the goal by doing this,
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
 
    animation.delegate = self; 
    animation.duration = 1.25f; 
    animation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut; 
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards; 
    animation.type = kCATransitionPush; 
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; 
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"]; 

add this in action after swipe.